# Having problems with Grub2 booting Ubuntu from my External Hard Drive

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, external-hard-drive, grub

I installed Ubuntu on my external hard drive but it won't boot on my laptop.  What do I do?

I did some reading and traced the source of the problem to Grub2.  Apparently, Grub2 doesn't use the device's UUID, and uses the linux directory instead (/dev/sdf2). This means that whenever I plug my E-HDD into a system that has a different number of drives connected to it, I won't be able to boot without editing the boot command. I don't understand it too well but that's what I got from what I read.

Is there any way to fix this?

Here's my grub config (trimmed to show example kernel entry).  I have no idea why it's not using UUID. I didn't tweak it once...

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry "Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-20-generic" {
        recordfail=1
        if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi
    set quiet=1
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-20-generic root=/dev/sdc2 ro   quiet splash
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-20-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-20-generic (recovery mode)" {
        recordfail=1
        if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-20-generic root=/dev/sdc2 ro single 
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-20-generic
}
```

Comment: I did the same and it works. Did you install the boot loader to the external or to the internal hard drive?

Comment: external... i think it has something to do with it not registering the drive properly... it keeps reading sdf when there's only sda and sdc... i think my hard drive is sdc

Comment: ubuntu's Grub2 does use the UUID, unless you've made some tweak.  please post your Grub configuration (*menu.lst* or *grub.cfg*).

Comment: i haven't tweaked anything... kind of a noob if you haven't noticed so i've been cautious so far and haven't played with any of the config files.

Comment: oh dear gawd, you're right, it's not using the UUID.  that's very odd.  which version of ubuntu are you running?  i'm going to assume Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic) based on the kernel entries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my device.map was not configured properly which led to grub using the ubuntu names, e.g. sdf2, rather than the UUIDs of the hard drive. the fix was to update device.map and then update grub2. It is done by running 'drivemap', i think, then update-grub. I'm not too sure on the command to update device.map because i did this about a week ago, but yeah. This is just in case anyone runs into my problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you're right that that's not grabbing UUIDs, which strikes me as odd.

Here's how a kernel entry *should* look (this is from my Ubuntu 9.10 VM, slightly tweaked but this should be fairly stock):

```
menuentry "Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-20-generic" {
    recordfail=1
    if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi
    set quiet=1
    insmod ext2
    set root=(hd0,1)
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set b22c7fe9-4354-40bf-b9bf-87a469289f6e
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-20-generic root=UUID=b22c7fe9-4354-40bf-b9bf-87a469289f6e ro
    initrd        /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-20-generic
}
```

The */boot/grub/grub.cfg* file is generated when something runs *update-grub* from the scripts in */etc/grub.d* and variables in file */etc/default/grub*.

---

- Now, there is a variable in the default file, ***GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID***, that if set to ***true*** will give a *root=/dev/sdXY* value to the *linux* kernel line (instead of a *root=UUID=...* value).  I don't think that's your problem, but check your */etc/default/grub* file to make sure.  You should see these lines (the `#` at the beginning of the line means it's commented out):

  ```
  # Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
  #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
  ```

  If you see *GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID* without the `#` at the beginning, insert it, save the file, and run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate *grub.cfg*.  Then check *grub.cfg* again to see if it looks right.

---

- If the defaults file looks OK, next check your drive's UUIDs themselves.  It's possible that the drive UUIDs aren't set correctly, or aren't getting detected correctly.  ***uDev*** has the job of creating symlinks in the device tree for disk UUIDs; check them:

  ```
  $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2010-04-18 04:15 b22c7fe9-4354-40bf-b9bf-87a469289f6e -> ../../sda1
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2010-04-18 04:15 e1c64ac1-186d-4c15-8833-6072ac6421df -> ../../sda5
  ```

  If this doesn't show you a partition you're expecting to see, you might need to check the filesystem directly with *tune2fs* ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/tune2fs.8.html)) (replace */dev/sda1* with the right device name):

  ```
  $ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep UUID
  Filesystem UUID:          b22c7fe9-4354-40bf-b9bf-87a469289f6e
  ```

  If this is missing, you can recreate it with:

  ```
  $ sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sda1
  ```

  Now re-check the *tune2fs -l* output, and then check */dev/disks/by-uuid* again.  You may need to reboot before uDev picks up the changes.  The ***update-grub*** scripts should now pick up the UUID, so re-run it and check the new *grub.cfg* to see if it looks right.

---

- If none of these are panning out, you may need to dig a little deeper.  Let's check our assumptions:

  - How is your boot drive partitioned?  (*fdisk -l*)
  - How is your boot drive formatted?  (ext2/3/4? FAT32? NTFS?)
  - Did you install via Wubi?

Comment: device.map isn't configured right apparently. i got ubuntu to work on my laptop but through trial-and-error (had to edit the parameters using 'e'). I know it's stupid, but is there a way to set device.map automatically or do i have to set it manually?

Comment: @anonymous: yeah, i've had to do that too.  i'm not sure offhand about redetecting device.map.  i've had to set device.map manually before;  it's mainly used to preset the relationship between /dev/sdX and (hdX); if devices aren't listed in it, Grub will assign (hdX) dynamically at boot time.

Comment: grub ain't setting it automatically... so do i just set the things i need? right now, my external is set to sdc2... should i just set it manually as in "(hd0) sdc"

Comment: @anon: honestly i'm not sure.  you could try with an empty device.map and see... but i think for that to have a prayer of working you'd need to get the UUID issue fixed.  there's a good Grub2 resource at http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20.html ... you might look through it for some ideas.

Comment: thanks... because of that link, i'm pretty sure i managed to fix it. i'll post the fix below